# Как сделать свой WYSIWYG Angular 2+?

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular5

Всем привет, пытаюсь нагуглить насчет WYSIWYG своими руками, но ничего не получается :). Могу попытаться сам сообразить с div contenteditable.
Мне нужно несколько кнопок, bold, link, задний фон у текста, и тултип для текста я как бы понимаю что такие вещи как задний фон и тултип врядли будут в ngx-editor и т.д. Может кто помочь пожалуйста, хотя бы на примере bold?

Comment: [froala](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg), [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html), делать свой wysiwyg это плохая затея, к тому же когда есть уже много чего готового :)

Comment: а тултип к тексту где мне взять? :)

Comment: самому сделать, то есть взять уже что-то готовое, наследовать директиву или компонент и допедалить что-то своими ручками